# Changing a programmatically generated uiwebview's content from a programmatically generated UITabBar

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift2, uitabbar

Sorry, I am using Swift 2 and am still a bit of a newb.  I have been able to programmatically create a UITabBar and UIWebView using the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIToolbarDelegate, UITabBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet var myWebView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var tabbar: UITabBar!
//    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView:UIWebView! = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 60, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 112))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//Add Webview
    let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 60, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 112))
    myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource ("index", withExtension: "htm")!))
    self.view.addSubview(myWebView)

//Add Toolbar for menu
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 46)
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    // make a button
    let menuButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "list-fat-7.png"), style:.Plain, target: self, action: "twitter")
    menuButton.tag = 1
    toolbar.items = [menuButton]
    //set toolbar color toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar)

//Add Tab Bar
    let tabBar = UITabBar()
    tabBar.delegate = self
    tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 52, self.view.frame.size.width, 52)
    tabBar.sizeToFit()

    // Tab Bar buttons
    let sermonButton = UITabBarItem(title: "Sermons", image: UIImage(named: "video-camera-7.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "video-camera-7.png"))
    sermonButton.tag = 1
    let bibleButton = UITabBarItem(title: "Bible", image: UIImage(named: "book-cover-7.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "book-cover-7.png"))
    bibleButton.tag = 2
    let calendarButton = UITabBarItem(title: "Calendar", image: UIImage(named: "calendar-7.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "calendar-7.png"))
    calendarButton.tag = 3
    let givingButton = UITabBarItem(title: "Giving", image: UIImage(named: "gift-7.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "gift-7.png"))
    givingButton.tag = 4
    let bulletinButton = UITabBarItem(title: "Bulletin", image: UIImage(named: "newspaper-7.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "newspaper-7.png"))
    bulletinButton.tag = 5
    tabBar.items = [sermonButton,bibleButton,calendarButton,givingButton,bulletinButton]
    self.view.addSubview(tabBar)
}
```

I then use this code to identify which "button" is pressed:

```
    //Mapping Tab Bar Buttons
    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.tag == 1 {
        self.myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"https://www.ustream.tv/combined-embed/10786920?social=0&videos=gallery&videosCount=4&html5ui")!))
    } else if item.tag == 2 {
        self.myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource ("index", withExtension: "htm")!))
    } else if item.tag == 3 {
        self.myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource ("Agenda", withExtension: "html")!))
    } else if item.tag == 4 {
            print("ApplePay")
    } else if item.tag == 5 {
            print("Bulletin")
    }

}
```

Pressing either button four or five prints the corresponding message, but pressing the other buttons returns a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)" error.  I have tried to resolve this by adding and removing self in the func tabBar with no success.  Can anyone see where my mistake is?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so for those who follow after me, here is the solution I created:

Step 1 I removed weak from the variable and created the frame in the IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet var myWebView:UIWebView! = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 60, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 112))
```

Step 2 I used the "!" to solve my unwrapping error:

```
myWebView!.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL:...
```

Step 3 I included the delegate in the class declaration:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIToolbarDelegate, UITabBarDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate{
```